Validity of Reasoning for every Cubic Polynomial having one Real Zero
I'm currently revising through the 12 Specialist Mathematics book from Haese and am on the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. One of the established properties of real polynomials is that "every real polynomial of odd degree has at least one real zero". My reasoning for this is as follows:
Any polynomial of degree $n$ can be factored into $n$ complex linear factors, some of which may be repeated. Additionally, if $a+bi$ is a zero then its conjugate is also a zero. If our polynomial in question is of an odd degree, ($2n+1$), then there will be $2n+1$ zeros. If we assume that all zeros are complex, then their conjugates must be a zero. As of this there must be an even number of pairs, and thus an even number of zeros, resulting in a contradiction.
I am wondering if this is a valid argument to support the statement.

This looks good to me, but we don't have to use contradiction (this is a minor point but some people consider a proof by contradiction to be less clear or aesthetically pleasing than a direct proof). If $A$ is the set of real zeros and $B$ the set of non-real zeros then an element of $B$ and its complex conjugate are always distinct. Therefore the number of elements of $B$ is even. Since the number of elements of $A \cup B$ is the degree of the polynomial, the number of elements of $A$ must be odd.

What you did is valid, but you can prove it in a faster way that doesn't even rely on knowing that complex numbers exist.
Since the degree of the polynomial is odd, we must have the that $lim_{-\infty}f(x) = -\infty$, and that $lim_{+\infty}f(x) = +\infty$. Now since polynomials are continuous, and we go from negative numbers to positive numbers, we must pass by 0 by the intermediate value theorem.
